# Gradient Tool is blocked on Illustrator cs6

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cs6, gradient

My gradient tool on Illustrator cs6 is blocked.

It won't let me change color, direction or anything related. The Gradient tool wont even let me click on the gradient, it shows the cursor with a `blocked` sign(circle and a diagonal line inside of it).

Seems very trivial a problem but I can't get to fix it. Did google the issue but to no avail. Please do help.

Answer (score 13):

**Solved:** Very very trivial, I just needed to click on the gradient window and toggle to `fill mode`, it had switched to `stroke`.

Also, googled why that happens and apparently if you have `transparent gradient` on your `stroke`, the `gradient tool` won't let you modify the gradient.

One of those things that Adobe takes on and stops developing I think.

Thank you if you guys tried to solve it :D

Comment: hey im having the same problem...but what do you mean by "fill mode" in gradient? could you describe the steps you took please? tx

Comment: Nice that you got it solved :) It would be good if you accept your own answer. This is good for everyone, to know at a glance that a solution to the question is to be found here.

Comment: this is a nice one. I had the same problem, thank u